# Show that $f:A \to [a,b]$

Tags: analysis

Let $f_n \to f$ uniformly in $A$.When $f_n:A \to [a,b] , \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$,show that $f:A \to [a,b]$.

That's what I have done so far:
$$$$
$a \leq f_n(x) \leq b \Rightarrow lim_{n \to +\infty}{a}\leq lim_{n \to +\infty}f_n(x) \leq lim_{n \to +\infty}b \Rightarrow a\leq f(x) \leq b$

Is that the proof or do I have to do also something else??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is all. You can see also that uniformily of the limit is not necessary. Only convergence was used.

Comment: Nice,thanks a lot!!